# How to target dynamic step elements with Intro JS

Tags: intro.js

I am trying to highlight an element which is created dynamically during the website tour (eg. it is created while going from *step2* to *step3*).

Intro JS cannot find it ( since I suppose all the step target elements are evalauted at startup with `introJs().start()` ) and so it defaults to `introjsFloatingElement` showing the modal in the center without highlighting any element...

Is there any way to avoid that or to load each step progressively? Thanks

Comment: Instead of using javascript to create HTMLs during the tour, you should create them up front with their CSS display set to 'none', and dynamically display them, which will work.

Comment: Yes I imagined that, but unfortunately it's not a viable option in my case

Answer (score 1):

My friend, I don`t know if you got the right answer for your problem but I had this problem too, and I fixed with

```
--https://jsfiddle.net/8dyxtyof/2/
```

You can use the intro.addStep() and pass a JSON like in the link above, it will solve your problem! (probably you`re already solved, but for those who still have this problem anwser is here)

BIG HUG!